# How can I disable node renaming for the TreeView in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, rename

Is it possible to disable the option to get into "Rename" mode when clicking on a tree-node?
I don't want to disable renaming completely, only to not allow doing it by clicking on the node.

Comment: Are you talking about setting LabelEdit property to false?

Comment: no, doing that will disable renaming completely. I don't want to do that.

Comment: What TreeView are we talking about?  WPF? WinForms?

Comment: How do you intend to rename the nodes ?

Comment: This sounds like an excellent idea. I mean, it would just be too easy to let users have UI idioms that they know and expect. It keeps them on their toes, keeps them keen.

Comment: LabelEdit has to be "true". then click on a node so it is marked in blue and then click it once more. wait a second or 2 and it will be in rename mode...

Comment: I'll let them do it through F2 or a context menu.

Comment: So turn `LabelEdit` off. Present an alternate UI for changing the name (such as a dialog containing a textbox that they can type the new name into) when they press F2 or select an item from a context menu. You can still change the name of the node programmatically when `LabelEdit` is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to turn the LabelEdit property on and off as needed:

```
    private void startLabelEdit() {
        treeView1.LabelEdit = true;
        treeView1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
        treeView1.LabelEdit = false;
    }
```

Beware that this has side effects, the LabelEdit property is a style flag for the native Windows control.  Changing it requires completely destroying the window and re-creating it from scratch.  The most visible side-effect is a small flicker when the window redraws itself after getting created.  There could be other ones, I didn't see anything go wrong myself.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why would you change the default behavior, but anyway here's a possible solution to edit the nodes with LabelEdit set to true.

Just catch BeforeLabelEdit event and cancel it, unless your specific action occurred. The following code does this for F2 key press:

```
        bool _allowNodeRenaming;

        private void treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_allowNodeRenaming)
            {
                e.CancelEdit = true;
            }

            _allowNodeRenaming = false;
        }

        private void treeView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
            {
                _allowNodeRenaming = true;
                treeView1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
            }
        }
```